# how to catch ofstream exception

Tags: c++, fstream

When writing into the file with `fstream` interface, I found the file would be corrupt sometimes. I tried to use `file.good()` and `file.bad()` to judge if there is an exception to catch, but unfortunately, I didn't catch any.

Therefore, I try to write the demo for it. when running the demo, I remove the `test.txt`. However, I don't receive any exception!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    std::ofstream ofile("test.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ofile << i;
        std::cout << i << ' ' << errno << ' ' << ofile.good() << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }

    ofile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ofstream exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337915/ofstream-exception-handling)

Comment: Unless you are seeking around or something else is also writing to the file you shouldn't get any corruption.  Does the above code give you any corruption?  If not can you make a [mcve] that does create the corruption?

Comment: Please note that `exception` and `catch` have a well defined meaning in the context of c++ related to handling and throwing exceptions. It can be misleading or confusing to refer to "checking for an error state" as "catching an exception". See [`throw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw).

Comment: The file is most likely corrupted because you wrote bad data to it, not because there was a problem with the stream.

Comment: By default, stream operations don't throw, so you won't be able to catch anything.

Comment: @molbdnilo One of the main features of iostreams is that they are type-safe - you cannot write "bad data" to them.

Comment: @NeilButterworth They may be type-safe, but they're not "value-safe" or "undefined-safe". I'm thinking dangling pointers, out-of-bounds indexing, plain calculation bugs, and so on.